# Different distance between two points on iOS and Android

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, distance

I'm trying to measure the distance between two points (longitude, latitude). My problem is that I get different results on iOS then on Android.

I've checked it with this [site](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/calculators) and the result was that the Android values are correct.

I'm using this MapKit method to get the distance in iOS: `distanceFromLocation:`

Here are my test locations:

**P1**: 48.643798, 9.453735 
**P2**: 49.495150, 9.782150

**Distance iOS**: 97717 m
**Distance Android**: 97673 m

How is this possible and how can I fix this?

Comment: They actually DO both use the same data:  See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I was having a different issue and stumbled upon the answer to both of our questions:

On iOS you can do the following:

```
 meters1 = [P1 distanceFromLocation:P2]
 // meters1 is 97,717

 meters2 = [P2 distanceFromLocation:P1]
 // meters2 is 97,630
```

I've searched and searched but haven't been able to find a reason for the difference. Since they are the exact same points, it should show the same distance no matter which way you are traveling. I submitted it to Apple as a bug and they closed it as a duplicate but have still not fixed it.  I would suggest to anyone who wants this to be fixed to also submit it as a bug.

In the meantime, the average of the two is actually the correct value:

```
 meters = (meters1 + meters2)/2
 // meters (the average of the first two) is 97,673
```

Apparently Android does not have this problem.

Comment: The magic of math. That will help me to calm the client. Is there any explanation for this or is this done for calculating the average distance between this two values?

Comment: I've searched and searched but haven't been able to find a reason for the difference.  Since they are the exact same points, it should show the same distance no matter which way you are traveling.  I submitted it to Apple as a bug and am awaiting a response.

Comment: Was showing distance at two different view controllers and it was different for same points. Debugged and debugged for 2 hours and found this was the reason. This is insane, should be fixed by apple! or at least mention it is non associative

Answer (score 3):

The longitude and latitude are not all that you need. You have to use the same reference model like WGS84 or ETRS89. 
The earth is not an exact ellipsoid, so you need models, none of the models are entirely exact, and depending on which model you use, distances are somewhat different.

Please make sure you use the same reference for iOS and Android.

Comment: OK, I'm aware of that but I can't set this models. It would surprise me if the MapKit framework uses a different calculation model on other platforms. platforms.

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one way to calculate distance between long/lat coords based on how you compensate for the curvature of the earth, and there's no right or wrong approach. Most likely the two platforms use a slightly different model.

Here are some formulae for calculating it yourself. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

If you absolutely need them to be the same, just implement your own calculation using one of these formulae, then you can ensure you get the same result on both platforms.

Comment: That would be my option if they really use different calculation models. It would interest me if  iOS and Android really use different calculation models.

Comment: Well MapKit is Apple code and Android is Google code, and even if MapKit uses Google's calculation algorithm, there's no guarantee that Google haven't tweaked it between successive versions of their maps software.